# pyspark how to plus between two RDDs with same key match

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

suppose I have 2 RDDs

where `RDD1 has (key1,key2,value)`

and  `RDD2 has (key1, value)`

Now I want to combine operation ( like + or minus ) from RDD2 to RDD1 where key1 has a match
here are example

```
RDD1 has [1,1,3],[1,2,2],[2,2,5]

RDD2 = sc.parallelize([1,1])
```

I want result

```
RDD3 to [1,1,4],[1,2,3],[2,2,5]  only the first and second data was added while third one wasn't
```

I try to use left outer join to find match on key1 and do some operation but I will lost the data that don't need to do operation is there a way to do operation in partial data?

Comment: Can you clarify what was the problem with doing a left outer join?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want pairwise operations or you data contains 1 to 0..1 relationships the simplest thing you can do is to convert both RDDs to `DataFrames`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, lit

df1 = sc.parallelize([
    (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 2), (2, 2, 5)
]).toDF(("key1", "key2", "value"))

df2 = sc.parallelize([(1, 1)]).toDF(("key1", "value"))

new_value = (
    df1["value"] +  # Old value
    coalesce(df2["value"], lit(0))  # If no match (NULL) take 0
).alias("value")  # Set alias

df1.join(df2, ["key1"], "leftouter").select("key1", "key2", new_value)
```

You can easily adjust this handle other scenarios by applying an aggregation on `df2` before joining `DataFrames`.